# How to solve second order linear partial differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Does anyone know how this equasion can be solved
$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}+f(x,y)z=0$$
where $z=z(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$ is some real-valued function? I was not able to find answer on it, and methods which I tried didn't work.